# Show all possible completitions in Emacs using auto-complete.el

Tags: emacs

I have auto-complete.el, using Emacs. When I type something, only part of the suggestion appears, and I want to set a key shortcut or something, to enable the whole thing and show all possible suggestions. Using it in Python mode.

When I first installed it, I used it once, don't remember how (possibly automatically).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
(add-hook
 'python-mode-hook
 (lambda()
   (define-key python-mode-map "\C-i" 'auto-complete)))
```

Comment: I am a bit new to Emacs. Added that to my .emacs file, closed emacs, opened it again, and it doesn't work. Should I create a keybind or something?

Comment: While in python-mode, type `f1 k C-i` and check the output.

Comment: Paste `(define-key python-mode-map "\C-i" 'auto-complete)` into `*scratch*` and press "C-j" and try again.